# How to create a generic type instance for the following situation

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i have the following code, please let me know how to create the instance at runtime without specifying the type while coding.

```
MyObject productobject = something.
```

i need the object of type

```
 AccessValuesFrom<long,double>,AccessValuesFrom<long,string>..etc
```

Generally i can create the object is below:

```
 AccessValuesFrom<long,double> accessData=productobject.ElementInfo.GetAccessValues<double>(something, something);
```

but i need the AccessValuesFrom at run time. long is pre-defined. how to create the instances for such type when there is no direct way of creating the instance(my situation i have to call

```
  productobject.ElementInfo.GetAccessValues<double>(something, something)
```

to create the instace.

Comment: What information do you have at runtime to indicate the generic type you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Type` object at this point, you can implement `GetAccessValues` like this:

```
object GetAccessValues(Type type, something, something)
{
     var result = Activator.CreateInstance(
           typeof(AccessValuesFrom<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(long), type));
     //do something with something
     return result;
}
```

also it'll be good to create an interface for all generic `AccessValuesFrom` with common methods in it.